# Spring AOP not working in main class with Spring Boot Project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to use spring aop in a spring boot project. I am not sure why I am not getting the advice weaved at the join point in main class. AOP is working well in a service class. The code is as below.

**SpringBootWithAOP.java**

```
package com.example.demo;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import com.example.demo.services.SayHelloService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWithAOP {

    @Autowired
    SayHelloService service;

    String message;
    static String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        name="George";
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWithAOP.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        service.message(name);
    }
}
```

**SayHelloService.java**

```
package com.example.demo.services;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SayHelloService {
    public String message(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello Dear User - " + name );
        return "Hello Dear User - " + name ;
    }
}
```

**MasterLoggerAspect.java**

```
package com.example.demo.aop;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class MasterLoggerAspect {
    @Before("execution(* com.example.demo.services.*.*(..) )")
    public void doForEveryServicesMethod(JoinPoint jp){
        System.out.println("hurray! In class: " + jp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + " - before method: " + jp.getSignature().getName());
    }
    //this advice is not getting weaved
    @Before("execution(* com.example.demo.*.*(..)) " )
    public void doForEveryMainClassMethod(JoinPoint jp){
        System.out.println("hurray! In class: " + jp.getClass() + " - before method: " + jp.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

**pom.xml** has **spring-boot-starter-aop** in the dependencies.

Could some one suggest where the problem exists.

Output -

```
hurray! In class: com.example.demo.services.SayHelloService - before method: message
Hello Dear User - George
```

Code available here: https://github.com/samshers/46692518/

Answer (score 3):

You need to use two dots notation (`..`) after service package to include sub-packages. Once you start using `* com.example.demo..*.*(..)`, all Spring managed beans will be logged except `main` and the method tagged with `@PostConstruct`. According to [PostConstruct JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html), this method MUST be invoked before the class is put into service.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MasterLoggerAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.demo..*.*(..))")
    public void logForAllMethods(){}

    @Before("execution(* com.example.demo.services.*.*(..) )")
    public void doForEveryServicesMethod(JoinPoint jp){
        System.out.println("hurray! In class: " + jp.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + " - before method: " + jp.getSignature().getName());
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.example.demo..*.*(..) )" )
    public void doForEveryMainClassMethod(JoinPoint jp){
        System.out.println("hurray! In class: " + jp.getClass() + " - before method: " + jp.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

If you add `@Component` annotation to the Spring Boot main class and autowire it to another class, then any method invoked in `SpringBootWithAOP` class will be logged. For example,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Component
public class SpringBootWithAOP {

    @Autowired
    SayHelloService service;

    String message;
    static String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        name="George";
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWithAOP.class, args);
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("888888");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        service.message(name);
    }
}
```

Changes to `SayHelloService` class,

```
@Service
public class SayHelloService {

    @Autowired
    SpringBootWithAOP aop;

    public String message(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello Dear User - " + name );
        aop.sayHello();
        return "Hello Dear User - " + name ;
    }
}
```

Here are the logged messages,

```
hurray! In class: class org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint - before method: message
hurray! In class: com.example.demo.services.SayHelloService - before method: message
Hello Dear User - George
hurray! In class: class org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint - before method: sayHello
888888
```

Comment: "and autowire it to another class, then any method invoked in SpringBootWithAOP class will be logged" - well this sounds fine. But still the `main` method and `@PostConstruct` method (`init`) are not joinpoints. I want to know how to achieve this. I want to log when these methods are invoked.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I should have used the qualifier that those two methods are not Joint Points. If you look at the Java doc of [PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html), you would notice that a class is not put into service until this method is invoked.

Comment: gr8. cheers for your reply. so similarly even `public static void main(String[] args) {...}` can not be traced through AOP. right?

Comment: It's not common at all. In my opinion, it should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

"Spring [AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) currently supports only method execution join points (advising the execution of methods on **Spring beans**)."

I do not believe the application Entrypoint  is a bean.

Look at [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html) interface and implementing your own class that overrides run.The Command Line Runner will run as soon as the beans are initialized.

Comment: Gr8 answer. I tried adding `@Component` anno on the main class. Hoped it would work. But no luck. Is this a limitation or i need to do any thing more. I want AOP logging on the main class also.

Comment: edited the answer.  try creating a new class that implements that interface above and your point cut should execute if the test is valid.

Comment: gr8. thx for response. I am more bothered about tracing `public static void main(String[] args) {...}` through AOP. does some way exists to achieve this?